# Django Rest sending param in url to queryset

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls, url-parameters

I was looking for answer in related topics, but none was working. So following Django Rest Guid about [filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) I wanted to add posibility to filter data via url.

I have my view:

```
class ArtistList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Artist.objects.all()
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        print(name)
        if name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        return queryset
```

and my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('artists/<str:name>', ArtistList.as_view(), name='artists'),    

]
```

When I provide url like: `http://localhost:8000/artists?name=A5` it's showing that this url doesn't exist.
I also was trying `http://localhost:8000/artists/A5` which lead to returning all artists instead of only 1.

I also was trying `re_path('^artists/(?P<name>.+)/$', ArtistList.as_view(), name='artists'),` like in the example in guide, but I still was getting an error. What is wrong here?

I have also second question. What is the best way to manipulate urls with params? I mean should I declare first url for returning all object and second for only specifc one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two things:

1. you have the *path* which is the part often the host and before the *querystring*, the querystring starts with `?`, so the path for `http://localhost:8000/artists?name=A5` is `artists`. The URL parameters are placed in `self.kwargs`; and
2. you have the *querystring* the querystring is a key-value pair collection that starts after the question mark, these items are stored in `request.query_params`.

If you thus want to filter with `/artists/A5`, then you work with:

```
# http://localhost:8000/artists/A5

class ArtistList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Artist.objects.filter(name=self.kwargs['name'])
```

In that case you always need to provide a name, since not providing one will, as you found out, return a HTTP 404 response.

If you want to use the querystring, you change the path to:

```
# http://localhost:8000/artists?name=A5

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('artists/', ArtistList.as_view(), name='artists'),    
]
```

and then you use `self.query_params` like you already did. In that case the `name=…` part is *not* required.

Comment: Thanks, again you are helping... It works, but instead of http://localhost:8000/artists?name=A5 I get http://localhost:8000/artists/?name=A5 and removing slash is not working

Comment: @Frendom: that might be the `APPEND_SLASH` setting (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash), or the browser, since normally the two should be equivalent.

Comment: I dont want to create similiar question, but what if we want to add another param (&) and use him to sort my data?

Comment: @Frendom: then you again take that parameter with `self.query_params.get('otherparam')`. It will automatically decode the `?...=...&...=...&....=...` to a dictionary-like object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the link `http://localhost:8000/artists?name=A5` just rename your path :

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('artists', ArtistList.as_view(), name='artists'),    

]
```

If you want to use `http://localhost:8000/artists/A5`, don't use query_params but kwargs :

```
name = self.kwargs.get('name', None)
```

In both cases, if you want to return a single object you might want to go for a detail view. (Using kwargs is usually associated with details view)